# Parsing XML Schemas and deriving metadata in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces

I have been looking at ways to parse XML Schema files for metadata of types defined in those files and get other information, and build the type hierarchy to be shown to the user.

I found a number of candidates:

1. Apache WS Commons XMLSchema API
2. Apache Xerces XML Schema API
3. XSOM
4. XMLBeans

XMLSchema API and Xerces XML Schema API seem the two best suited. 
While XMLSchema API was easier to use, it is not as well documented, and Xerces seems to be the one with much more support. However, I have been unable to locate any resources which might help me get started with the Xerces XML Schema API, except their FAQ's which have proved to be highly inadequate.

So my question is twofold - Which is the better choice for parsing and querying **Schema** files, and there any resources for these two to get started quickly?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at Xstream, it's a good instrument for serialization, but you also can use it for parsing. [Here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) is two minute tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something specifically to parse schema files, and get the defined elements, types etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might consider is Saxon's SCM format, which is an XML representation of the schema component model. Both SCM and XSOM are closely based on the schema component model defined in the W3C specs, and rely heavily on the user understanding that model; they don't repeat the documentation of the component model in the API definitions.